# Groovy def l = [1, 2, 3] as BlockingQueue

Tags: groovy

If I write something like `def l = [1, 2, 3] as Socket` which is obviously nonsense, I get this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[1, 2, 3]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.net.Socket'
```

That makes sense.

Now I try something less adventurous:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue

def l = [1, 2, 3] as BlockingQueue
println l.class
println l
```

This doesn't throw an exception, and prints the following:

```
class ArrayList1_groovyProxy
[1, 2, 3]
```

So what's `ArrayList1_groovyProxy`, and why am I able to cast the list to `BlockingQueue` without error despite the fact that it fails (`l` doesn't end up being an `BlockingQueue` instance)?

Edit:

- First of all, I'd like to point out that `def l = [1, 2, 3] as List` works well, and produces a regualr instance of `ArrayList` despite the fact that both `List` and `BlockingQueue` are interfaces.
- Second, after [Dónal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648/d%C3%B3nal) answer, I tried the following:

  ```
  def l = [1, 2, 3] as BlockingQueue
  assert l instanceof BlockingQueue
  println l.class
  println l
  ```

  This printed the following lines and no **assertion exceptions were thrown**:

  ```
  class ArrayList1_groovyProxy
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```

  However, this line does throw a `MissingMethodException`:

  ```
  l.offer(5)
  ```

  So the assertion somehow succeeds, but trying to use `l` as a BlockingQueue throws an exception.
- Third, the same happens if I try `def l = [1, 2, 3] as Map`
  This code:

  ```
  def l = [1, 2, 3] as Map
  assert l instanceof Map
  println l
  println l.getClass()
  ```

  produces no errors and prints:

  ```
  [1, 2, 3]
  class ArrayList1_groovyProxy
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just Groovy being cute.  It's able to see that you're trying to create a collection, but it can't figure out how to construct a BlockingQueue.  It's falling back to a proxied ArrayList. If you'd gone with a type declaration on the left side instead of a "def," it would have blown up.  Again, it's getting cute because you're using a def.  Annoying, isn't it? :)

Comment: How common is this "cuteness"? Casting that fails quietly can lead to nasty, hard to spot bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `x as y` is **not** casting, it's Coercion (see [Section 8.7 of the Groovy Manual](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_coercion_operator)).

Coercion does not check type safety when casting.

Also, `BlockingQueue` is an interface. I'm not sure why you would cast an object as an interface.

Try running this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue 
LinkedBlockingQueue l = [1, 2, 3] as LinkedBlockingQueue
println(l instanceof LinkedBlockingQueue)
println(l.class)
println(l.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique())
​
```

You get:

```
true
class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
[add, addAll, clear, contains, containsAll, drainTo, element, equals, getClass, hashCode, isEmpty, iterator, notify, notifyAll, offer, peek, poll, put, remainingCapacity, remove, removeAll, retainAll, size, take, toArray, toString, wait]
```

You can't have an instance of an interface, so it had no idea what you asked it to do. For instance, try running `new BlockingQueue()`, you can't because you can't have an instance of an interface. This is why you cannot cast an Object to be an interface.

Comment: `def l = [1, 2, 3] as List` works fine although `List` is also an Interface. I get `class java.util.ArrayList` and `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Malt I... I don't know what you mean by "works fine". That's still not valid, you can't instantiate interfaces, try `new List()` or `new BlockingQueue()`. You can't, as an interface is defining the *contract*. You can't fulfill a new contract on a pre-existing entity that was not constrained by the contract initially.

Comment: I'm well aware of the difference between a concrete class and an interface. However, the statement `def l = [1, 2, 3] as List` produces a working `ArrayList` without error despite the fact that `List` is an interface. When I tried `def l = [1, 2, 3] as BlockingQueue`, I expected to get an instance of a `LinkedBlockingQueue` or some other implementation. Instead, I got something weird.

Comment: @Malt You get an ArrayList for List, the same as you got an ArrayList for the cast to blocking queue **because it was an ArrayList in the first place**. The default collection object in groovy is ArrayList, and your cast didn't do much except change some stuff in the metaClass. Casting to an interface just inherently doesn't make sense, and is the answer to your question. I agree though, it's weird, but you're doing something weird in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense, and it explains some of the weirdness, but not all of it.

Comment: @Malt http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_coercion_operator this is why, I forgot using `x as y` is VERY different than traditional casting.

Comment: Of course I understand that casting is not the same as coercion. Casting wouldn't have created such strange results. That's not what the question is about. `ArrayList` doesn't have an `asType` method and the documentation you linked doesn't explain what happens when I coerce types with no such method or when I coerce to an Interface. It seems that groovy permits this, but behaves unexpectedly. So I want to understand the mechanism that leads to this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> why am I able to cast the list to BlockingQueue without error despite the fact that it fails (l doesn't end up being an BlockingQueue instance)?

Why are you so sure that `l` is not a `BlockingQueue` instance? The following (which you can run in the Groovy console) indicates that it *is* a `BlockingQueue` instance:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue

// this assignment would be impossible if l is not a BlockingQueue
BlockingQueue l = [1, 2, 3] as BlockingQueue

// this assertion would throw an exception if l is not a BlockingQueue
assert l instanceof BlockingQueue
```

FYI, you can remove a lot of uncertainty about types by defining the types of your variables, rather than using `def`.

Comment: And even more by using `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic`

Comment: `l` isn't a blocking queue because A) the class name is `ArrayList1_groovyProxy` B) `l.offer(5)` throws a `Groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:`. The fact that the assert doesn't fail only makes this behavior stranger. Also, I appreciate static typing tips.

Comment: It _definitely_ is a `BlockingQueue`, the assertion and the assignment to the variable of type `BlockingQueue` would fail if it weren't.