# Groovy BlockingQueue.poll, "No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.poll"

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to use the `BlockingQueue` Java class from within Groovy, and according to [this geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/blockingqueue-poll-method-in-java-with-examples/) article you can poll for elements with a timeout using `.poll(some_long, some_time_unit)`

The problem I'm having is that this errors out.
The following groovy script:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
bq=[1, 2, 3] as BlockingQueue
bq.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Gets the following error:

```
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.poll() is applicable for argument types: (Long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$4) values: [1, SECONDS]
Possible solutions: pop(), tail(), tail(), sort(), clone(), wait()
```

What is the correct way to use the `BlockingQueue.poll` function from Java in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195462/groovy-def-l-1-2-3-as-blockingqueue) question.

As a workaround you could use comething like this :

```
def bq = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10, false, [1, 2, 3])
bq.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

this uses constructor with 3 parameters from [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#ArrayBlockingQueue(int,%20boolean,%20java.util.Collection)) :

- first parameter is capacity
- second is `boolean` which describes fairness - in other constructors in defaults to `false`
- a `Collection` with initial data

If you would like a different implementation of `BlockingQueue` you could also look at [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) :

```
def bq = new LinkedBlockingQueue([1, 2, 3])
bq.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

but the concrete implementation should be chosen according to your needs. The major difference between those two is that `LinkedBlockingQueue` is implemented based on linked-list and `ArrayBlockingQueue` is implemented based on array. Also `LinkedBlockingQueue` is optionnaly bounded and `ArrayBlockingQueue` is always bounded.

Comment: Thanks! `ArrayBlockingQueue` worked like a charm. I upvoted your answer, but couldn't mark it as accepted since the question got marked as a duplicate.